# How to authenticate a site with Python using Requests?

Tags: python-3.x, request

How can I get this to work? I've been trying for days and keep hitting the same dead ends. I've tried all the examples I could find to no avail.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'login_username': 'login', 'login_password': 'password'}
url = 'http://rustorka.com/forum/login.php'
requests.post(url, data=payload)
r2 = requests.get('http://rustorka.com/forum/index.php')
print(r2.text)
s.cookies
```

Comment: Instead of requests.post try s.post, then s.get

Comment: this does not work... (